# pyInstaller can't find data files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a python script into a standalone executable using pyInstaller.

My script contains two data files, named 'input.txt' and 'output.txt', both of which can be found in the script's root folder.

Here is the script using the files:

```
    input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')
    output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

It works perfectly when I run it in pyCharm, reading the input.txt and writing the output.txt.

To compile it to an executable using pyInstaller, I used a .spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['KHTools.py'],
         pathex=['/Users/rafaelcarmo/PycharmProjects/KHTools'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[ ('input.txt', '.'), ('output.txt', '.') ],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```

The files were created in the root folder of the executable, and they even contain the same data as the original files, so I believe it was a sucessful .spec creation.

However, when I run the code, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KHTools.py", line 62, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'
[17561] Failed to execute script KHTools
```

I really don't understand it. The file is there in the bundle (input.txt), it has the same content it had in the original file, and it returns this error.

Does anybody knows what I did wrong?